# How to map properties from an object to a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, automapper

I want to map values of properties from one class to a list

```
public class category
{
    public int? categoryACount { get; set; } // 1
    public int? categoryBCount { get; set; } // 2
    public int? categoryCCount { get; set; } // 3
    public int? categoryDCount { get; set; } // 4
}
```

```
public class categoryList
{
    public string categoryType { get; set; } //categoryA,categoryB,categoryC,categoryD
    public string categoryCode { get; set; } //A,B,C,D
    public string categoryDescription { get; set; } //ADesc,BDesc,CDesk.DDesc
    public string categoryQuantity { get; set; } //1,2,3,4
}
```

Here the structure of the classes are different and based on the `categoryType`. I want to map it to `Category` class. The value of `categoryQuantity` for each `categoryType` to be mapped with the properties in `Category` class.

If `categoryType` is "CategoryA" the value from `categoryQuantity` to be mapped with the `categoryACount` of `category` class

Comment: The _Getter_ on the `categoryList` properties is fairly easy to write.  Do you really want a _Setter_ - what would it mean

Comment: You should work with an enum. I also would advice you to follow a training on programming what will help you to understand programming concept.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: When I invoke Map() method occurs the following error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

Comment: .ForPath(dest => dest.employees[0].firstName, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Client.FirstName));  the problem is the error doesnt say much about it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
List<categoryList> ocategoryList = new List<categoryList>();
ocategoryList = yourCategoryListData();

category ocategory = new category();
ocategory = yourCategoryData();

foreach (var item in ocategoryList)
{
    switch (item.categoryType)
    {
        case "categoryA":
            item.categoryQuantity = ocategory.categoryACount.ToString();
            break;

        case "categoryB":
            item.categoryQuantity = ocategory.categoryBCount.ToString();
            break;

        case "categoryC":
            item.categoryQuantity = ocategory.categoryCCount.ToString();
            break;

        case "categoryD":
            item.categoryQuantity = ocategory.categoryDCount.ToString();
            break;
    }
}
```

> Hope this will work.